# Vue custom directives

Tags: javascript, angular, vue.js

I need a solution to get all inputs in my vue app and then do something with them i.e styling.

I am thinking about using directives for this.

I always use this way when I work on angular project, where I can create a directive, which has a selector i.e

```
selector : input[type="text"]. 

export class MyCustomDirective {

constructor(el) {}

.............

}
```

and then when I start my app I get all inputs of the app without adding the created directive to them one by one.

Unfortunately Vue directives are not able to do this, because I must prefix the created directive with v-

so this wont work

```
Vue.directive('input', {

bind: function (el) {

// some magic

},

});
```

any help or new ideas ?

Comment: I see what you mean. I havent encountered such feature yet in Vue. I know I've used this in the past in Angular. Maybe you can get away with defining an input `component`; I think that should cause Vue to mount your input component when it sees `<input ...>`

Comment: why wouldn't you just use css to target the inputs or create an input component with styling?